# git ls-remote throws fatal: HTTP request failed

Tags: git, ssl, redhat-enterprise-linux, tls, jenkins

when jenkins tries this command:

`git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git`

it fails and breaks the build, trying the same command in the console got the same error message:

```
[userr1@DEV-ECM ~]$ git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git
error:  while accessing https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

does anybody has got the same problem? any solutions? :(

**edit 1:**

```
    [userr1@DEV-ECM ~]$ ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.253.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-112-iad.github.com (192.30.253.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=134 ms
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-112-iad.github.com (192.30.253.112): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=152 ms
64 bytes from lb-192-30-253-112-iad.github.com (192.30.253.112): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=131 ms
```

**edit 2:**
trying to access the url from the desktop in firefox got this error:

[ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoEY1.jpg)

Comment: The system is offline or can't access https://github.com for some other reason.  This isn't a git issue; it's a networking issue.

Comment: @jayhendren server can ping github.com

Comment: ping (ICMP) is not the same as HTTPS connections; they're different protocols entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there where two things we did that solved the problem:

1. updated curl (and libraries that curl depends on),
2. add the google public dns servers,

I'm not sure the point 2 helped or was relevant but still it was the 2 only changes we did,